# During update, Ubuntu (22.04) goes to crash dump screen from which I can't quit

Tags: command-line, updates

I'm running 22.04 on an Acer Aspire dual boot with Windoze.

- Secure boot is off.
- UEFI enabled.
- Windows fast start disabled.

Also to mention is I haven't started this machine for maybe 2 months so the updates are probably a bit in arrears.

Two or three days ago I ran an update and it said that I could only do a partial upgrade. I deleted two obsolete entries in the repos and let the machine continue. I forget exactly but IIRC it eventually went to a crash dump screen, but since I needed to do stuff in the Windows OS, I did a restart with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SYSRQ</kbd> + REISUB.

Today I booted Ubuntu again, it seems like some updates were installed, but others not, as there was no network. I did a USB tether and proceeded `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`.
It was quite a large upgrade, and the usual line showed up  `X-Y-Z will have to be downloaded Y/n ?`I replied `y`. After that it continued happily installing the updates, the last normal screen I saw it was unpacking the video drivers.

When I came back it had gone to the panic dump screen that you see in this image below, and is logging continuously as I type. (over 2 hours now)

Do I wait, if so how long could this take? Or do I force a reboot? Or is there a way to exit this screen?

[image: hanging_update]

Update: After quitting with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SYSRQ</kbd> + SUB and rebooting, the terminal now says `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.'`

When doing this, it just goes to a black screen with cursor.

Comment: That pic isn't very clear, but it looks like a kernel panic from the top section. Alt-SysRq-B is pretty much all you can do with that.

Comment: Thanks, I was using the same cellphone as its USB tether :) I'll let it run for a while then terminate it.

Comment: "*[I]t said that I could only do a partial upgrade*" A 'partial upgrade', if your account is accurate, suggests a pre-existing wrong-version or non-Ubuntu package. Find and remove that package.

Comment: @user535733 I deleted 2 entries from the "Other Software" in the "Software and Updates" panel. I think it was them.

Comment: Deleting a package source does not uninstall the blocking package. It merely keeps that package from getting upgrades.

Comment: As a matter of interest, there is no "Other Software" checked at the moment. Even Gimp. I unchecked yt-dlp and I think Java leaving nothing checked in that window. Is it not possible that there are too many updates outstanding?

Comment: In future: Partial updates are bad news. If you are presented with one, it means that there are major problems in your package system. Decline the update and resolve the problems before proceeding. For now: Can you get into recovery mode through grub? If so, you would be able to work on the package system problems. To reiterate/restate what @user535733 said, *just removing a flawed source fixes nothing*. You must remove the software already installed from the flawed source.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It boots okay after Alt + SysRq + SUB and I managed to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` now and it exited okay. I will keep on looking for any rogue packages and see what it does at the next update.